# Web crawler. Error LAttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tr'

Tags: python, web-crawler

My code gives an error on this line: tr_**tag = soup.table.tr**.

Error message: non type object has no attribute 'tr'.

I'm writing a web crawler on `imbd` to get data using Python 2.7.
Could you help me to fix it?

```
def get_movie_data(self, soup, min_rating):
 **tr_tag = soup.table.tr** 
 tr_next = tr_tag.next_sibling.next_sibling
        data = []
        movie_data = {}
        while tr_next:
            td = tr_next.contents[5]
            name = self.get_movie_name(td)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_movie_data(self, soup, min_rating):
    if soup.table:
        tr_tag = soup.table.tr
        tr_next = tr_tag.next_sibling.next_sibling
        data = []
        movie_data = {}
        while tr_next:
            td = tr_next.contents[5]
            name = self.get_movie_name(td)
```

Can you try this?

Comment: Still be error in if soup.table, thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you passing the 'soup' argument correctly? What is the print statement of soup?

Comment: I downloaded source on  https://github.com/girish3/imdb-crawler/blob/master/imdb_crawler.py . I have just started learning python, so I don't know much. I'm sorry to disturb you.